# Android: random and textView

Tags: android, textview

I have just started learning Android and got some misunderstanding. I'm trying to create an application which displays a textView and a button. Every button click generates a new random number which should be displayed in the textView.

But unfortunately my code causes a list of errors. Here it is:

```
public class FirstAndroidProjectActivity extends Activity {

public OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(101);
         tv.setText(i);

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   button.setOnClickListener(listener);    
    }
}
```

If I just don't use random and use some string except of **i** 
(for example **tv.setText("99");**) everything is ok, but it doesn't work with a variable as a parameter of setText().

Where is a mistake?

Hope for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert your random number to a string before setting the text on your TextView

Try

```
tv.setText(i +"");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't auto convert types. The + operator is overloaded to transform the parameters passed to it into a String when one or more of those paramaters is a String.  So, when you pass i + "" to setText() you are passing a String, however if you just pass i then the compiler sees you passing an int to a method that expects a String and lets you know that that can't be done.

Comment: setText accepts ints along with strings. The problem is that if you pass setText an integer it tries to find a resource ID with that value which is why he was getting a crash at run time instead of in the compiler.

Comment: @dymmeh, very good point. Eclipse can't know if that arbitrary int is or isn't a valid resource ID, so, it obviously lets you set it. This is the pitfall of multiple signatures. You can accidentally pass something in that looks right to the compiler and will cause a crash at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

i is an int, try tv.setText("" + i);

Answer (score 0):

Convert your integer to a String before setting it to the textView. You should also move `Random r = new Random();` outside of the method, or else your numbers may not really be random :

```
Random r = new Random();

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    int i = r.nextInt(101);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

From the documentation :

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers

If you create two `Random` objects too quickly (for example the user clicks two times on the button very quickly), they will share the same seed (the system clock is used to generate it) and as a result you will get the same number two times.

By creating only one `Random` instance in a global variable, you avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
tv.setText(new Integer(i).toString()) ;
```